# how to automatically extract strings from project and add them to resx file in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resx

I have a very large wpf project and after two years of development i requested to make it bilingual, is there any way to automatically extract strings in labels and grid headers in xaml files so i can translate them instead of manually extract them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any existing tool to help, but you can implement it yourself, I faced such a problem when I was converting a large solution of above 100 C++ projects from ansi to unicode strings, I implemented a simple tool with one window containing 2 rich edit boxes, one for the original text with replaces colored, and other for the replacement, for manipulating the resex files have a look at [Working with .resx Files Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx), Don't forget that regular expression is your friend to accomplish this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this process by finding all `Label` controls in WPG root `Grid` element (e.g. `mainGrid`) and extracting their content using the following C# code snippet:

```
IEnumerable<Label> _collection = mainGrid.Children.OfType<Label>();
foreach(Label _control in _collection)
{
    string _text = _control.Content.ToString();
    // add you code here
}
```

The results can be placed in Resource file (for example, CSV) with your translation added. Other solution (more sophisticated) pertains to the creation of multilingual XML file, or the local multilingual database with all label contents added to the first field, translation added to the next fields, etc.

Hope this may help.